# Как cменить JPanel на лету?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Делаю простенькую игру на Java.
Представление следующее:
Имеется `JFrame mainFrame;`, на нём `JPanel menuPanel;`, на котором `JButton btnToGame;`. Хочется, что бы при нажатии на кнопку menuPanel исчезала, но не разрушалась, а вместо неё появлялась `JPanel gamePanel;` уже со своим содержимым, но на ней тоже должна быть кнопка, допустим `JButton btnToMenu;`, которая опять возвращает нас в меню.
Пытался писать так, но при нажатии на кнопку уже нарисованное виснет, а новое не появляется. Хотя если растянуть окно, то содержимое обновляется, но моё окно должно быть нерастяжимым.

```
public class MainFrame {

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel menuPanel;
    private JPanel gamePanel;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
        frame.go();
    }

    public MainFrame() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Game Title"));
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);

        menuPanel = new JPanel();
        menuPanel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        menuPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        gamePanel = new JPanel();
        gamePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        gamePanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        mainFrame.add(menuPanel);

        mainFrame.setUndecorated(true);
    }

    public void go() {
        JButton btnToGame = new JButton("To Game");
        JButton btnToMenu = new JButton("To Menu");

        btnToGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mainFrame.removeAll();
                mainFrame.add(gamePanel);
            }
        });

        btnToMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mainFrame.removeAll();
                mainFrame.add(menuPanel);
            }
        });
        menuPanel.add(btnToGame);
        gamePanel.add(btnToMenu);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию `JFrame.pack()`, она позволяет "пересобрать" содержимое всего фрейма. И вместо `removeAll()` стоит использовать `remove(Component comp)`. Возвращаю рабочий код:

```
public class MainFrame {

private JFrame mainFrame;
private JPanel menuPanel;
private JPanel gamePanel;

public static void main(String[] args){
    MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
    frame.go();
}

public MainFrame() {
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Game Title");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setSize(800, 600);
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);

    menuPanel = new JPanel();
    menuPanel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    menuPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

    gamePanel = new JPanel();
    gamePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    gamePanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

    mainFrame.add(menuPanel);

    mainFrame.setUndecorated(true);


}

public void go() {
    JButton btnToGame = new JButton("To Game");
    JButton btnToMenu = new JButton("To Menu");

    btnToGame.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        mainFrame.remove(menuPanel);
        mainFrame.add(gamePanel);
        mainFrame.pack();
    });

    btnToMenu.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        mainFrame.remove(gamePanel);
        mainFrame.add(menuPanel);
        mainFrame.pack();
    });
    menuPanel.add(btnToGame);
    gamePanel.add(btnToMenu);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Это, действительно, помогло, но при этом размеры `mainFrame` сбросились, почти, до размера кнопки.

Comment: По-моему это не проблема. Таким образом вы удаляете лишнее. Если вам нужно оставить пустое место, можно установить минимальные размеры панели: panel.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(x, y));